# SQL Server - distinct value from multiple(2) columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

suppose I have two columns of integers, A and B. Now I want distinct values from these, meaning if both A and B have 1, I want 1 only once.

Note: I am NOT interested in getting distinct rows. I just want to get unique integer values from this table which could either be in A or B

I could insert values of A and B in one column of some temp table and do a select distinct over that column.

Anything more sophisticated (performancewise)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that should work, I think:

<strike>select all the distinct A's, then all the distinct B'
 UNION ALL these two sets
 select DISTINCT from that unionized result set
     SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
       (
         SELECT DISTINCT A FROM YourTable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT B FROM YourTable
       )</strike>

With Lukáš' help, you can simply write:

```
     SELECT A FROM YourTable
     UNION 
     SELECT B FROM YourTable
```

since as he rightfully points out, the regular UNION returns no duplicates. You don't even need to have a DISTINCT clause on your individual SELECTs - quite ingenious! Thanks, Lukáš!

Marc

Comment: If you change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`, you can avoid the outer query as `UNION` itself will return only distinct values.

Comment: And you don't even need `DISTINCT` on the inner queries either.

Comment: ah, interesting - that's new to me though - let me check - indeed! Interesting - so the UNION totally "distinctifies" the result set - thanks!